# Does Office 2007 Outlook "autoreply" only reply if you are in "To" Address?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Does anybody know the rules of when outlook autoreply will send and when it will not? We want to be able to have it set to send to "everyone outside of the organization" so that whenever you receive an email it will notify them you are out of the office.

HOWEVER:
Quite a large number of us receive emails that come to other addresses. Emails that go to our general "contact us" form get sent out to several people, for example. I get a copy to make sure the form is working correctly, others actually decide want to do with it, etc.

We don't want my auto-reply to send to people, unless they explicitly send it to me. Does anyone know how this works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Typically it replies to everyone.

In the Out of Office Assistant, you can define more rules to customize this so that it excludes certain domains, addresses and/or subject lines.

Answer (score 0):

I would go into the Out-of-Office Assistant's rules section and experiment with the From: and To: options, to see what happens in each case.  I don't think you can get super specific with how it handles it, though.  It'll most likely end up replying to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In the Out Of Office Assistant it presents you with two different tabs. One for Internal reply one for Outside the Organization. If the address forwarding to you is an internal address, you shouldn't trigger the OoOA if you only have an external message sent